What does はむりと mean?
彼女も僕に続いて卵サンドを手に取り、はむりと口に含む
It sounds like a onomatopoeia but I cant find anything about it in any of my dictionaries or google

I think ハム is the onomatopoeia of biting down on something (as opposed to モグ being more about chewing and swallowing it)? There's coincidentally(?) [食]{は}む with a meaning you'd expect from the kanji; but grammatically, the form here seems like it would have to be ハムる. I was able to find that as slang (also), but it doesn't make sense here to me, whereas something to do with eating or biting would.

This is an onomatopoeia はむはむ, which was turned into はむり following this pattern. This may not appear in the traditional dictionary, but is common in manga. Here's the entry of はむはむ in Pixiv百科事典. あむあむ is a variation of this.
はむはむ describes the action of taking soft bites or holding food in one's mouth. This is considered cute and is often associated with babies, young girls, or small animals.

I don’t think はむり(と) itself is common expression, but it can be understood in relation to another onomatopoeia はむはむ, which typically depicts (repetitive) love-bites/play-bites. (https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%81%AF%E3%82%80%E3%81%AF%E3%82%80)
It focuses on closing mouth with something between the lips and basically does not mean biting it in terms of applying pressure with teeth, or further aiming to crush or cut it off.
It is by far more common to use ぱくぱく to describe eating (or repeated opening and closing of mouth), but はむはむ seems for me a softer and gentler.

Fun aside:  ぱくぱく is the literal sound of Pacman (that's where the name comes from), while hamsters go はむはむ.
